# decorate method after declaration

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class from a library, let say `MyClass` with a method `my_method`.

```
from MyLibrary import MyClass
obj = MyClass()
result = obj.my_method('arg')
```

I can't thouch the original implementation, but I want to decorate the `my_method`, in particular I want to check if the returning value is `not None` and in case to raise an exception, as:

```
result = obj.my_method('arg')
if result is None: raise ValueError()
```

this is quite boring since I need to do it many times. In particular I don't want to change the code when I am calling `obj.my_method('arg')`. I am trying to:

```
def safe_method(self, *args):
  result = self.my_method(*args)
  if result is None: raise ValueError()
  return result

MyClass.my_method = safe_method
```

this is not working:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I understand why, but I can't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decorate it like this:

```
def safe_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        result = func(self, *args)
        if result is None:
            raise ValueError()
        return result
    return wrapper

MyClass.my_method = safe_decorator(MyClass.my_method)
```

You can then reuse this decorator for whatever method you want from whatever class definition. This is what the `@` notation does more or less :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
def safe_method(self, *args):
  result = self.my_method(*args)
  if result is None: raise ValueError()
  return result

MyClass.my_method = safe_method
```

What is happening above is you are replacing MyClass.my_method with another method that in turn calls my_method. Hence, you are getting a recursion error.

Try this:

```
MyClass._my_method = MyClass.my_method

def safe_method(self, *args):
    result = self._my_method(*args)
    if result is None:
        raise ValueError()
    return result

MyClass.my_method = safe_method
```